# How to find longest string here?

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to find the longest string in a nested list using the below code

```
table_data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

cnt = [""]*3
for tab in range(len(table_data)):
    for liel in table_data[tab]:
        if len(liel) > len(cnt[tab]):
            cnt[tab]=liel
print(cnt)
# ['cherries', 'Alice', 'moose']
```

The above code is returning the longest string in each list, but I think its long code, is there any other way to do this?

Expecting any ways to do this using List comprehension or function

Regards

Comment: What do you want if two strings share the same max length?

Comment: @user3483203 , at present its returning the first string ,

Answer (score 8):

> Expecting any ways to do this using List comprehension

Yes, list comprehension is a good choice.

```
>>> [max(row, key=len) for row in table_data]
['cherries', 'Alice', 'moose']
```

Comment: No.  There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: max(x,key=len),1,np.array(table_data))`?? are you looking for a specific way? why?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve your result would be to use the `map` function, althouth this does not utilize list comprehension:

```
table_data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

output = list(map(lambda data: max(data, key=len),table_data))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['cherries', 'Alice', 'moose']
```